# Java Swagger not generating service where endpoint response type is List<T>

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am trying to use swagger with java.
Using NSwag studio I am able to generate all my endpoints except one that returns a list of objects.
Here is my action in controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "getAll", nickname = "getAll", responseContainer = "List", response = DiakEntity.class)
@GetMapping("/api/diakok")
@ResponseBody
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
public List<DiakEntity> GetDiakok() throws Exception
{
    ServiceObjectResponse<List<DiakEntity>> request = _diakService.getAll();

    if(!request.getIsSuccess())
    {
        throw new Exception(request.getMessage());
    }
    return request.getObject();
}
```

I am using swagger-annotations 1.5.23, springfox-swagger-ui 2.9.2, springfox-swagger2 2.9.2.
If I test from Postman it works.

Also tried like this:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "getAll", nickname = "getAll")
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, responseContainer="List", response=DiakEntity.class, message = "Gets all diak objects")
    @GetMapping("/api/diakok")
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<DiakEntity>> GetDiakok() throws Exception
    {
        ServiceObjectResponse<List<DiakEntity>> request = _diakService.getAll();

        if(!request.getIsSuccess())
        {
            throw new Exception(request.getMessage());
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(request.getObject(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

thnx

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the following annotation for swagger.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "getAll", nickname = "getAll")
@ApiResponse(code = 200, responseContainer="List", response=DiakEntity.class)
```

Comment: still nothing. :(

Comment: Your return type should be `ResponseEntity<List<DiakEntity>>`

Comment: OK, but the second example still not get generated.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I changed my action as below, and it started to work

```
@ApiOperation(value = "all", nickname = "all")
    @PostMapping("/api/diak/all")
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_CLIENT')")
    public List<DiakEntity> GetAll(@RequestBody @Valid RequestDiakByName data) throws Exception
    {
        ServiceObjectResponse<List<DiakEntity>> request = _diakService.getAll();

        if(!request.getIsSuccess())
        {
            throw new Exception(request.getMessage());
        }
        return request.getObject();
    }
```